SQL Query improvement, connecting two subqueries
In our system there is a report "Products and sales",
Its calculation takes place on the server,
Databases used in the request:

Orders: id, checkPrice
OrderItems: id, orderid, checkPrice
Products: id, productName

It is necessary to calculate the following parameters to generate a report for a day for some store:

The number of orders delivered
The number of pickup orders
The number of items sold (salesCount)
The amount of sales (salesRevenue)

Initially, the request looked like this:
select
   oi.ProductId,
   p.Name ProductName,
   sum(case when o.Type = 1 then oi.Count else 0 end) deliverycount,
   sum(case when o.Type = 2 then oi.Count else 0 end) pickupcount,
   count(oi.orderid) salesCount,
   sum(o.checkprice) salesRevenue
from
    OrderItems oi
    join Orders o on o.Id = oi.OrderId
    join Products p on p.Id = oi.ProductId
where
    not o.IsRemoved
    and o.ExecutionDate between @BeginDate and @EndDate
    and (@TradeObjectIds = array[]::bytea[] or o.UnitId = any(@TradeObjectIds))
group by
    oi.ProductId, p.Name;

The problem is that as a result of the received records, the amount of sales and the number of sales are more than the actual one (because several different orderitems can be used in one order, which is why the calculation of the amount of sales is duplicated)
Initially, I saw that the aggregate function count() has the keyword distinct
Using it didn't help me to count only the unique oi.orderid
It turns out that I have to turn one query into 2 and connect them using Union
select sum(sq.itemscount) as generalitemscount,
    sum(sq.orderscount) as generalorderscount,
    sum(sq.itemspricesum) as generalitemspricesum,
    sum(sq.orderssum) as generalorderssum
from(
select 
    sum(oi.count) as itemscount,
    0 as orderscount,
    sum(oi.checkprice) as itemspricesum,
    0 as orderssum
from orderitems oi
inner join orders ord on ord.id = oi.orderid
    and not ord.isremoved
    and (ord.state = 0 or ord.state = 9)
    and ord.executiondate between '2024-04-02' and '2024-04-02 23:59:59'
    and o.UnitId = any(@TradeObjectIds))
inner join products p on p.id = oi.productid and not p.isremoved and p.producttype = 0
where not oi.isremoved
union all
    select 0 as itemscount,
    count(o.id) as orderscount,
    0 as itemspricesum,
    sum(o.checkprice) as orderssum
    from orders o
    where not o.isremoved
    and (o.state = 0 or o.state = 9)
    and o.executiondate between '2024-04-02' and '2024-04-02 23:59:59'
    and o.UnitId = any(@TradeObjectIds))
) as sq

The query works correctly, but the solution doesn't look perfect to say the least
Of course, there is an option to make two different requests after all and connect the data already on the server, but suddenly you can offer something interesting

Note that you have two checkPrice columns, one in the Order table, and one in the OrderItems table, where the first is the cost of the whole order, which may constist of several items, and the second is the cost of the individual item.
In your original query you have sum(o.checkprice) salesRevenue, if you instead do sum(oi.checkprice) salesRevenue it should probably solve your problem.
